# Отключить всплывающие окна в Windows 10 для сенсорного экрана чтобы не мешало при работе интерактивной выставки

Tags: unity3d, windows-10, тач

Сделали приложение для ПК для сенсорного экрана на Unity.  Столкнулись со следующей проблемой, не знаем как отключить стандартные жесты и поведение системы, как то движение от левого или правого края экрана к центру. От правого края наше приложение сворачивается и открывается выбор окон запущенных приложений. При движении от правого края появляется панель быстрого доступа (нашел в сети что называется она CharmsBar).

По CharmsBar в сети нашел статью где советуют как отлкючить ее при помощи правки реестра, правда статья для Win 8 (http://winreview.ru/kak-otklyuchit-panel-charms-bar-v-windows-8/)

Как называется вторая функция не знаю.

Также мешаются уведомления, которые могут выскакивать и сворачивать полноэкранное приложение. Но по этому вроде нашел как отключать в параметрах, буду пробовать.

Нам необходимо либо отключить все эти навороты через систему, либо добиться в Unity чтобы мы перехватывали все события от тача и не давали их системе.
У кого есть подобный опыт?

Comment: Вы хотите отключить нормальное поведение системы потому, что юзер будет пользоваться только вашей программой, а нормальное поведение системы ему, разумеется, не нужно, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: да все верно. У нас интерактивная выставка, нам не нужно чтобы кроме нашего приложения что-то пользователь видел

Comment: Тогда имеет смысл написать об этом в самом вопросе, иначе это выглядит как деструктивное поведение программы.

Comment: @VladD подправил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

Откройте панель управления (выберите отображение в виде значков) и нажмите на иконку мыши.

В свойствах мыши нажмите на вкладку "Настройки устройства" и затем на кнопку "Настройки".

Снимите флаг с "Угловые свайпы" (или как-то так, оригинал - *Edge Swipes*) и нажмите "Применить->Ок".

Нажмите "Применить->Oк" в свойствах мыши.

Comment: По словосочетанию `Edge Swipes` нашел вот такую инструкцию для отключения https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/48507-enable-disable-edge-swipe-screen-windows-10-a.html . Буду пробовать

Comment: Эксперимент прошел удачно, через настройку групповой политики прав для Windows 10 Pro все получилось без правки реестра.